# Can I retroactively fix "delete add" that should have been "move and update"?

Tags: git

I have a rebased branch (1 commit) where a series of files that have been moved and updated are showing up as delete + add.

Is there a way to retroactively fix this?

I'm wondering about creating a new branch, cherry picking the changes from the existing (but not committing yet). And at this point can I force git to treat the (delete + adds) as move + update. Is something like this possible?

Comment: May we ask why this matters to you?  In general, moving files around in Git can cause problems for your history, because Git can't always track files across move operations (or delete + add operations...it shouldn't make a difference how it is being presented to you).

Comment: There are changes in other branches against files that have moved. I'd like to rebase those changes into my own branch. So I moved A,B,C to AX,BX,CX. Git recorded this as delete+add. I now want to rebase in changes against against A,B,C. How do I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Have you completed the rebase already?  If so, the most important thing IMO is that it was done correctly, not whether a moved file shows up as delete + add.

Comment: I want to rebase. The conflict is that incoming wants to change a file, but locally that file appears deleted (which isn't correct, it was moved). My local branch has never been shared, so I don't mind rewriting its history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Fiddle with the strategy option argument for rename detection.  Depending on your Git vintage, this is either `-X find-renames=threshold` or `-X rename-threshold=threshold`.  Use `git diff` to determine an appropriate threshold value; in `git diff` this is the `-M` or `--find-renames` parameter.

Remember that cherry-picking is implemented as merge, with the merge base being the parent of the commit being cherry-picked, the `--ours` commit being the `HEAD` commit (as usual), and the `--theirs` commit being the commit you are cherry-picking.

#### Long

Git never *records* anything as a rename operation.  If you rename a file and commit, Git simply records a new snapshot.

Consider, for instance, the typical [Spot the Difference puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference).  You are given two pictures and asked to figure out what's different.  If the left-side picture is "before" and the right-side picture is "after", and a chair goes missing, you would say "the chair is removed".  If a different chair appears in a different location, you might say "the one chair is removed and the other one is added".  But what if the two chairs look the *same?*

You could say: Chair A is removed, and chair B is added, as you do when the two chairs look very different.  Or, you could say Chair A has *moved* to position *B!*  (But has it really?  Maybe chair A was removed, and a different chair B was added, and you just can't tell the difference.  There are some deeper philosophical questions here, as we are about to see.)

Anyway, Git's snapshots are like the pictures.  They don't contain any *movement*, ever!  That's up to someone *comparing* the snapshots, even if that someone is Git itself.  You tell Git: *compare, for me, snapshot A and snapshot B.*  Git will report a file as *moved* if it's gone missing from one name in A, and the exact same contents have appears under another name in B, *and* you've told Git: "check things to see if they have moved, too."

This is your basic `git diff <commit-L> <commit-R>`, where rename-finding is enabled with the `-M` or `--find-renames` option.  (L here stands for the Left side, and R for the Right.)  Git will find such renames if the files are 100% identical.  But what if they're not—what if the chair moved, but gained a few scratches along the way?

Git will consider a "moved file" to be *the same* file as some original file if it meets a *best match* criterion.  Essentially, Git first finds all the files that that seem to have disappeared from commit L, and all the new files that seem to have been created in commit R.  It places all these names into a *rename candidate queue*.

Then, for each such file, Git compares all the L files against all the R files.  (As you might guess, this is fairly compute-intensive.  There are a bunch of internal optimizations here, including first doing a fast check for 100%-identical, which is very easy for internal-to-Git reasons.)  Git computes a *similarity index* for each pairing.  If the similarity index exceeds the threshold you chose—or 50% if you did not choose one—Git considers this pairing a candidate.  Git chooses the *best* such pair, which is the one with the highest similarity score.

Having found the best pairing, the two files are removed from the rename candidates queue.  These two files are now *identified as the same file*, or in our chair analogy, as "the same chair" in the left and right side pictures, just moved and maybe scratched-up a bit in the process.

**I call this the process of determining file identity.**  Philosophically speaking, this is Git's answer to the problem of [the Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus), or more informally, the [Grandfather's Axe paradox](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheseusShipParadox).  "This is my grandfather's axe.  My father replaced the handle, and I replaced the head, but it's still the same axe!"  Two files are *the same* file once they have been identified as such.

For speed's sake, Git defaults to pairing-up any two files in commits L and R as "the same" if they have the exact same name.  With `git diff`, you have the option to *break* this pairing, in case it is wrong; this puts more file names into the rename-detection queue, making it take longer.

#### That's all about `git diff`; what about `git merge`?  (And why `git merge` when I'm cherry-picking!)

We'll get to why in a moment, but let's talk about `git merge` now.  When we use Git, we use `git merge` to *combine* changes that were done across two different lines of development—typically, two different branches—often by two different people.  In order to combine these changes, Git must first locate the *point at which the work diverges.*  This point is the *merge base*, and since Git is all about commits, this amounts to finding the *common commit* between the two lines of work.

This all makes a lot of sense when we draw it as a picture of commits.  Each commit remembers its *parent* commit—the commit that comes just before this particular commit—so we can draw commits left to right, with older commits at the left and newer ones at the right, like this:

```
...  <-o  <-o  <-o  ...
```

Suppose Alice and Bob both start with a common source repository—both ran `git clone` on the same Git repository, for instance—so that they have some series of commits ending in the *most recent* commit on `master`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

The name `master` contains the actual hash ID of some commit `H`, which Git calls the *tip of the branch*.

Now Alice does some work and makes a new commit or two.  Her commits get new, unique hash IDs that will never be used anywhere else by anyone else:

```
             I--J   <-- master (Alice's)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
```

Meanwhile, Bob does some work and makes a new commit or two, and his commits get new, unique hash IDs that will never be used anywhere else by anyone else:

```
             I--J   <-- [Alice's master]
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             K--L   <-- master (Bob's)
```

Once we somehow get *all* the commits together into a common repository, we have two *branches*, Alice's master and Bob's master, with a *common starting commit*, the original `master`:

```
             I--J   <-- alice/master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- bob/master
```

We can do this whether we are Alice, Bob, or some third person Carol, as long as we have the *commits*.  The commits are what matter!  The *names*—here I'm using `alice/master` and `bob/master` to locate commits `J` and `L`—are just there to help us find the commits.

It's now perfectly obvious that Alice and Bob both started with commit `H`, so it now becomes easy to see *how* Git will merge Alice's work with Bob's work: Git just needs to *compare*—i.e., `git diff`—commit `H` against `J` to see what Alice did, and compare `H` against `L` to see what Bob did.  So Git does that:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what Alice changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what Bob changed
```

Note the `--find-renames` option here, which uses the default "50% similar" metric to locate any files that were renamed, while Alice or Bob were working.  (Worth thinking about: why doesn't Git need to look at any of the *intermediate* commits?  This is especially important because it might, in some cases, help with that rename detection.  Git doesn't do it, though.)

In any case, Git now *combines* the two sets of changes, applying the combined set of changes to the snapshot from the merge base.  The result, if it all goes well, gets committed as a new *merge commit* that goes after our current commit—whichever of these two branches has `HEAD` attached to it.<sup>1</sup>

When you run `git merge`, you can give Git a `-X rename-threshold` argument, just as you can give `git diff` such an argument.  Merge just passes that same number to diff, to control how strict or loose the rename-detector should be, in determining file identity.

---

<sup>1</sup>We didn't draw `HEAD` in, so are we adding to `alice/master` or `bob/master`?  Until Git goes to make the commit itself, it does not really matter!  Well, that's not quite true.  It does matter in case of *rename conflicts:* if both Alice *and* Bob renamed some particular file, which name should Git use?  It will use whichever name is in the `HEAD` commit, by default.  It also affects how the work-tree file gets marked-up, in the case of the more typical merge conflict.

---

#### Cherry-pick (finally!)

When you use `git cherry-pick`, Git consider this a funny kind of merge.  Let's draw out some commit chains again and see how this works:

```
...--o--*--o--P--C--o--o   <-- branch-X
         \
          o--o--L   <-- branch-Y (HEAD)
```

The name `HEAD` here is attached to `branch-Y` to indicate that `L` is the commit we have checked out right now.  This commit is the `--ours` commit.  Commit `C` above is the one we want to cherry-pick (C for Cherry), and `P` is its parent.  (I know `P` could stand for Pick but I needed a letter for Parent, so P is for Parent and C is for Cherry.)  Most of the other commits are uninteresting—we never need their hash IDs, so we just show them as `o`.  I marked one `*` as it's the obvious merge base, but actually Git is not going to use that either!

What Git will do now is to run a merge, as if we ran `git merge`, except that instead of *finding* the merge base, which would be commit `*`, Git just *uses* the parent `P` as the merge base.  Git now runs:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-P> <hash-of-L>
```

to see what *we* changed—Git is going to try to keep these changes!—and then:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-P> <hash-of-C>
```

to see what *they* changed, in their one commit that we are cherry-picking.

Git will now combine these changes, just as it always does for any merge, with the potential for merge conflicts.  As you have now seen, the `--find-renames` depends on the *similarity index* values of the files as stored in commits `P`, `C`, and `L`.  Git *must* detect the renames between `P` and `L` in order to identify particular files as *the same* file, otherwise it won't know how to combine the changes to that file.